# CSS, how to add picture in the corner of every columns

Tags: html, css

I have three columns and I need to add a picture in the right-top corner of every columns.

Here's the full source: http://jsfiddle.net/5aFzh/2/

And here's short overview.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
            <p class="clear"></p>
.... my content
        </div>
        <div id="center">
.... my content
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <p class="clear"></p>
.... my content
        </div>
        <p class="clear"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body  {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;  
    margin: -16px 0 0 0;          
    padding: 0;        
}

#outerDiv {
    width: auto;       
    margin: 0 auto;    
    height: 1110px;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    height: 1110px;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#center {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    height: 1110px;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    overflow:scroll;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    height: 1110px;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

The picture doesn't matter, just small image of something.

Thanks

EDIT: it should be the html element, then I can interact with it.

Comment: You can't add an element via CSS, you can only style elements that already exist. However, since you say that you want to be able to intereact with it via jQuery, why not just add the element via JavaScript?

Comment: The edit section is **why** I posted that comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make you divs `position: relative`

So you can set the position of the image inside of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/5aFzh/8/

**EDIT**

Why are you using: `margin: -16px 0 0 0;`

That's not really what `margin` is for and will bite you in the ass later.

Comment: It's because of my browser (Chrome), thanks for warning, i'll remember it

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to columns called "column" and add a background image property

```
background-image:url('image.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
background: url(yourimage.png) no-repeat;
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it should be the html element, I will interact with it by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
#left, #center, #right {
    background:url(image.jpg) top right no-repeat
}
```

Or if all `div`s in `#content` are columns, you can simply do:

```
#content div {
    background:url(image.jpg) top right no-repeat
}
```